Firebase auth currentUser is always null
I am trying to protect a route in web app using load function ,reading the value of currentUser from auth to see if the user is logged in but it is always null. So when I refresh the page I am kicked out.
// src/routes/protected/+page.ts

import {redirect} from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
import { authUser } from '$lib/authStore';


export const load = async () => {
    const  user = get(authUser);
    if (!user) {
        throw redirect(302, '/login'); 
    }
    return {};
};


Here is the Login page code:
<!-- src/routes/login/+page.svelte -->
    <script lang="ts">
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import {onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
    import {auth} from "$lib/firebase";


    let email: string = '';
    let password: string = '';

    const login = () => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(() => {
                onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {if (user) {const uid = user.uid}});
                goto('/protected');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
            });
    };
</script>

And Finally here is my Authstore file where I use onAuthStateChanged():
// src/lib/authStore.ts
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './firebase'; 

type AuthUser = {
    uid: string;
    email: string | null;
} | null;


export const authUser = writable<AuthUser>(null);

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        authUser.set({
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email
        });
    } else {
        authUser.set(null);
    }
});

And typical firebase initialize file plus that I tried to stop it from reinitializing an app:
// src/lib/firebase.ts
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp, getApps} from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

const app = getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];
export const auth = getAuth()

I tried:

to use onAuthStateChanged instead and implement a listener.
to stop firebase from reinitialize in refreshes.
implement a function with await to see if there is delay on vale update.
Enforcing firebase persistence mode.
It's a +page.ts. And I tried changing the values of ssd and csr as well to know how rendering affect this.

The result was always the same. null as currentUser, or undefined as svelte store.

Answer on why the code you shared doesn't work is below. In your list of things you say that you tried onAuthStateChanged already, but since you don't share a minimal repro of that, we can't say why it didn't work for you.

I added the repo at the end of my question.

Sorry, but the minimal repro needs to be inside the question itself. I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, and updating based on that.

@FrankvanPuffelen Done.

Oof... that's quite a few files. How/where is src/lib/authStore.ts loaded? If you console.log(user) inside the onAuthStateChanged on there, what does it output? If that never logs a user, the user credentials likely aren't persisted where that code runs (e.g. client-side vs server-side).

@FrankvanPuffelen It is loaded on src/routes/protected/+page.ts where I check the svelte store value. I made a mistake on pasting that file's content so you probably missed. When I put a logger, It's always print null! but I don't get it, It shouldn't be.

That's the expected behavior on page load. When the app/page load, Firebase automatically restores user credentials from local storage. But to do that it has to make a call to the server (a.o. to check if the account was suspended) and that is an asynchronous call, which won't be completed before the page loads. So the user account will be restored (typically shortly) after the page has loaded.
You will need to use an auth state listener to capture the user sign-in, as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on getting the current user.

I already tried creating a authStore.ts file and use onAuthStateChanged and writing the value of uid to a Svelte Store then checking that value here. But it was also undefined. I didn't call it after login because doc said this will be automatically updated after signInWithEmailAndPassword(), which I used for login.
Can you make an example of how can I effectively use it?
